# Deploying simple SPA to Azure though Git

Tags: angularjs, node.js, azure, sass, azure-web-app-service

I have just a simple Angular app I'm trying to push up to Azure though git. I've modified my deploy.sh file to run `npm install` `bower install` and `grunt build`, but it builds to a directory called `dist`. Azure doesn't seem to pick up on that at all, so how do I get them to host it? Do I need to have an Express server pointed to dist or something?

Comment: Have you reviewed Continuous deployment using GIT in Azure App Service - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/  ?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't have any information about using using grunt to build my app and how to host it after it does.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've got all your bower/grunt tasks working and everything you need is in the /dist folder, the easiest thing is to change the mapping of the root of your website.  Then it will run correctly in Azure without changing your local dev setup.

In the non-preview portal, for your web app on the "Configure" tab, at the bottom under "Virtual Applications and Directories" update the path for `/` to  `site\wwwroot\dist`

Comment: When I do this, I just get this message `Server Error in '/' Application.`

Comment: would need to see the detailed error messages from the site to help out further, which i'm glad to do if you want to post them

Comment: He means the whole error message. Take a look at this blog post for more references on how to obtain access to those logs: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/waws/archive/2014/09/24/azure-website-siteextension-to-view-eventlogs.aspx

Comment: Yes, you can find a ton of information in the SCM site associated with your azure website - it's just <yoursite>.scm.azurewebsites.net (you ca also view logs in Visual Studio). You may need to turn detailed logging on, and possibly failed request tracing also - take a look here as well: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue and for now I've changed the site to point to a repo hosting just the dist files (so running grunt on my local and checking in).

Answer (score 0):

In Azure management portal for the web site, under application settings you need to create an app setting called as 'Project' and mention set it to relative path of 'Dist' folder. After dong this, once you push changes to git, those changes first gets pushed under 'Repositories' folder and then KuduSync process will sync 'Repositories' and 'wwwroot' folders. Hope that helps.